# Sandbox rejects credit card numbers

Tags: sandbox

Why does PayPal Sandbox reject a credit card, which it accepted before, saying, "The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a different debit or credit card number."

I have tried different numbers with the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adam. I tried two different credit card numbers from the list, a Visa and a Mastercard number. The Visa number was rejected with "The card you entered ..."

The Master Card number redirected to the old style input form and the Sandbox had filled in the credit card number with its own value. I filled in the rest of the form and it was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

By 2021, the list of credit cards doesn't work. You need to use the Credit Card Generator and a "sandbox account" with the same respective country to generate the card number.

Generate with: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/creditCardGenerator/

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have noticed that none of the test credit card from Paypal works.

What I did to complete the checkout process was

- login to the developer.paypal.com dashboard
- Sandbox > Accounts page
- Create Account as buyer via the button at top right corner.
- Create a card during the sandbox account creation process.
- Once it is done, click on the newly created account and click on 'Profile'.
- Go to Funding tab for credit card detail.

I have used that credit card and was able to checkout successfully.